# Large table with geospatial data - slow queries during updates

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I have a large table with millions of rows (geospatial data) which is getting updated several times per day.

Selects by lat/lon are very fast (0.02-0.04 seconds) most of the time, but during updates the same queries can take as long as 5 seconds. Profiling shows them hanging either in the "sending data" or "statistics" state. Of course there is a lot of I/O going on during these mass updates which are also quite time-consuming because every row needs to be updated.

The storage engine used is InnoDB, though I had to keep buffer pool size at 128M (a larger buffer pool appears to put more strain on the server during update/cleanup operations which even results in failed/stalled connections).

Any suggestions for tuning? I wondered if maybe there is a way to specifically limit I/O write operations or prioritize Selects over Updates/Inserts (with the latter ones not being that time-critical).

Table structure:

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vt                | datetime    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lat               | double      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lon               | double      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
[lots of data fields]
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
max_connections=100
thread_cache_size=1
long_query_time = 1

open_files_limit=8192
table_cache=3000
table_open_cache=4000
table_definition_cache = 3000
query_cache_limit=256k
query_cache_size=100M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
thread_cache_size=5
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=2M
join_buffer_size=2M
max_heap_table_size=4G
key_buffer_size=3G
tmp_table_size=4G
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

Comment: Whats your server config? and increasing the InnoDB buffer pool will not slow down any process. Becuase all your updates/inserts/deletes will happen in memory itself. Share your table structure and indexes details.

Comment: I have added the info. Each time I tried to increase buffer pool size to 12G (total RAM: 32 GB), there were still slow queries during updates and after a day or so, the database server went unresponsive with mariadb showing "too many connections" (which didn't happen even once with the default setting)

Comment: You mentioned `UPDATEs` that hit the entire table?  Let's see them.  And whether any indexes are involved in such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`INSERT DELAYED`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-delayed/) to avoid blocking `SELECT`s:

> When a client uses INSERT DELAYED, it gets an okay from the server at
>   once, and the row is queued to be inserted when the table is not in
>   use by any other thread.
>
> Another major benefit of using INSERT DELAYED is that inserts from
>   many clients are bundled together and written in one block. This is
>   much faster than performing many separate inserts.

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent for [`UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/update/). You can do [`REPLACE DELAYED`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replace/) (which first deletes the existing row if one exists and then inserts a new row), but that's probably not useful to you.

A few other maybe useful optimizations:

[`innodb_flush_method`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_flush_method)`= O_DIRECT`

[`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit)`= 2`

Maybe consider if the geometry types ([POINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/point/)) would be useful instead of your `lat`, `lon` doubles. Geometry types are [indexable in InnoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/spatial-index/) as of MariaDB 10.2.

Looking at your configuration, I think your query cache is set quite large. (Though it might make sense in your specific case, I don't know.) This can result in degraded performance due to lock contention, as the query cache is locked while it's updated.

I can see how the query cache might make sense in your use case if you're not writing to the database all that frequently. Note however that [MySQL is retiring support for the query cache in MySQL 8.0](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/). I don't know what the fate of the query cache is on the MariaDB side.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
key_buffer_size=5M  # from 3G because minimum MyISAM data used
query_cache_size=64M  # from 100M to reduce QC overhead when TBL changes
tmp_table_size=320M  # from 4G for 1% of RAM available
max_heap_table_size=320M # from 4G - should always be same as tmp_table_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 128M default to 25% of RAM
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 1M - when 128K will be higher performance
join_buffer_size=128K  # from 2M - when 128K will be higher performance
thread_cache_size=50  # from 1 AND remove SECOND line in my.cnf-ini
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 2K to increase QC capacity of RESULTS
```

After 3 days of uptime, please post (here or at pastebin.com):

- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`
- `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`
- complete `Mysqltuner.pl` results for more complete analysis and suggestions.

thread_cache_size=5 is TOTALLY inadequate for 100 max connections - see refman.

Comment: @Felidae - Have you yet provided these?

Comment: @Felidae What is your current situation?  Made any progress?  Any plans to post SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; SHOW GLOBAL VARAIBLES: mysqltuner.pl results?